# IntelliJ - show all compilation errors automatically in the project when code is changed

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, when I make any code changes it automatically shows all compilation errors in the workspace in a console. It seems like in IntelliJ I have to make/build the project in order to see any compilation errors. Is there a window/tab to show all compilation errors?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nowadays you have the same option as in eclipse to have automatic builds when you save.

[image]

---

**Edit**

Any changes in the editor will now trigger a compilation either when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is pressed or after a short interval.

This first image will show a main method and a class with a simple `print` method. No compilation errors.

[image]

In the next image I have removed the parameter `message` in the `print` method. That's the **only** thing I did, I did not even save I just waited a couple of seconds. And then suddenly the compilation error is shown below because the caller of the method has now supplied too many arguments.

[image]

Comment: Actually I thought it would work that's why I accepted your answer but I tried it and it didn't seem to work. I tested it by removing a parameter from a method, and expected to see an error for the caller of the method but I didn't see anything in the problem console. Is the error supposed to show up automatically?

Comment: @Glide I don't know what kind of problem you have because for me it is working flawlessly. I added some screenshots which proves that there are no problems whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots! The delay sometimes took awhile for me so I wasn't able to see it. Pressing Ctrl+S like you suggested did speed it up.

Comment: For me it shows the error sometimes only when I open the java file directly. I would like to see all errors immediately in the project tree. For example when the interface changes. Somebody also had this issue?

Comment: It only shows up with the "auto compile" listed:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/problems-tool-window.html

Comment: For newer versions (e.g. 2017.1 like mine), it's `Build project automatically`, just in case anybody's searching for `Make` in Settings(like me)...

Comment: I have tried "Build project automatically", but it extremely slows down big projects (gradle with multiple subprojects for example). And in contrast to exlipse, the difference is big: In eclipse, I see a list of all files which fail; in intelliJ, I only see one file which doesn't compile, because then the compile run stopped. When fixing a chain of problems for example, add a throws to functions over 5 levels, it takes me ~3 minutes in eclipse but 30 minutes in intelliJ by repeatedly building